# Variables are not avaliable in Android Studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio, variables

I just started learning flutter with android studio. There is nothing wrong with the code i use but it gives tons of errors there are also 13 data analysis errors. I think it might be because the app doesn't have variables but like i said i just started learning so I have no idea why this is happening. Please help.
[image]

I tried reinstalling Android Studio and updating the plugins there is nothing wrong with them. Code also works on other devices.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you  need just open   android   terminal and type

```
flutter clean
```

and after  that

```
flutter pub get
```

and second best

```
ctrl+alt+y
```

for  reload all from disk

Answer (score 0):

try getting the pub using

1. `flutter clean`
2. `flutter pub get`